# Squid running out of filedescriptors on CentOS 7

Tags: squid, centos7, file-descriptors

I'm running Squid 3.3 (EPEL) on CentOS 7 and recently I have been getting the following error message in my `cache.log`

```
WARNING! Your cache is running out of filedescriptors
```

I am slightly confused by this because I seem to have ample descriptors available:

```
squidclient mgr:info | grep 'file descri'
Maximum number of file descriptors:   16384
Available number of file descriptors: 16326
Reserved number of file descriptors:   100
```

Squid was also compiled with this flag:

```
--with-filedescriptors=16384
```

Squid confirms that these are actually available on startup:

```
2015/08/18 21:11:45 kid1| With 16384 file descriptors available
```

However this error keeps occurring. Not long after this error is logged the `squid` process seems to also hit 100% CPU or use nearly all of the system memory up over 90%, causing the internet speed to drop to a crawl or just hang indefinitely. Killing the process and restarting resolves it but eventually it will happen again.

I have a total of 8 GB of memory available, these are the memory/cache related parameters in my `squid.conf`

```
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 16000 16 256
cache_mem 1024 MB
```

I am also using `ufdbguard` and additional helper plugins for Kerberos and NTLM authentication.

Any advice?

Comment: Provide dmesg output

Comment: Nothing useful, mostly firewall

Comment: Have you tried solutions like this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/squid-proxy-server-running-out-filedescriptors/ ?

Comment: How much files in your cache directory? 

find /var/spool/squid -type f | wc -l

Comment: No, because the descriptor value as it is now seems fine? Most examples show the problem when the descriptors are a low value like 1024, this isn't the case here.

Comment: Cache value is 43409. I guess that's quite a lot, but I have enough disk space/RAM in theory.

Comment: I think you don't understand what file descriptors is. Increase number of open files in /etc/security/limits.conf to 65535

Also provide output of  sysctl fs.nr_open

Comment: I'm beginning to understand now, the cache directories value reported is greater than the current descriptors so it needs to be increased right?

Comment: Yep. Each file descriptor is integer associated with opened file. Check man 2 open.

Comment: `ulimit -n` now 65535, `fs.nr_open = 1048576`

Comment: Okey, restart squid and check for result. You should edit sudo vi /etc/default/squid as link says:)

Comment: Squid reports `With 16384 file descriptors available` still

Comment: Have you edited /etc/default/squid?

Comment: Yes, but in my case it would be /etc/sysconfig/squid, as CentOS 7 is systemd.

Comment: grep max_filedesc /etc/squid/squid.conf

Comment: Set as the same value as ulimit, no change. I am getting `NOTICE: Could not increase the number of filedescriptors` in my cache.log now however. I don't know if SELINUX might be blocking it

Comment: Please clarify have you restarted squid after all changes?

Comment: Yes full restart of squid process with systemctl, I haven't rebooted the server itself however.

Comment: Provide output sysctl fs.file-max

Comment: `fs.file-max = 777240`

Comment: Actually i am missing something. Doublecheck with ulimit command that limits for files are correct.

Comment: ulimit reports `65535`

Comment: I think its down the the compile value being hard coded.

Comment: I am in the same boat. If you run `squid -v` you will see the compile option `--with-filedescriptors=16384`, this is the wall your hitting. I am debating what to do next myself. I am considering just compiling from source and bumping the descriptors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of file descriptors is set in the systemd unit file. By default this is 16384, as you can see in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/squid.service`.

To override this, create a locally overriding `/etc/systemd/system/squid.service` which changes the amount of file descriptors. It should look something like this:

```
.include /usr/lib/systemd/system/squid.service

[Service]
LimitNOFILE=65536
```

Do not edit the default file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/squid.service`, as it will be restored whenever the package is updated. That is why we put it in a local file to override defaults.

After creating this file, tell systemd about it:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

and then restart squid.

```
systemctl restart squid
```

Comment: Interestingly `squidclient mgr:info | grep 'file descri'` still reports the same value, despite changing it in systemd. I think the fact its compiled with that value is a problem.